# Observer class, what it's and what should do

Tags: javascript, class

i'm trying to learn a little more of Javascript and so i'm reading some books and making some excercises to practice what i'm learning. One of the excercises says the following:

1-Create a Movie object:

Movie

-attributes : hashmap

- play()
- stop()
- set(attr:string, value)
- get(attr:string)

2- Add a MovieObserver class that listens for "playing" and “stopped” events.

I did the following:

```
function Movie(){
this.attributes = {
    title : 'undefined',
    duration : '0',
    director : 'undefined',
    actor : []
}
}

Movie.prototype.set(attr , value){
    this.attributes[attr] = value;
}

Movie.prototype.get(){
    console.log(this.attributes['title']);
    return this.attributes['title'];
}

Movie.prototype.play(){
    console.log ('Playing '+this.attributes['title']+'...');
}

Movie.prototype.stop(){
    console.log ('Stopped '+this.attributes['title']+'...');
}
```

What i need to know is what the MovieObserver should do, i can't understand that.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid syntax.

Comment: Technically JavaScript has no classes, but basically they are implemented as functions. You do: `function ClassName(){ ... }` like you did on `Movie`. Also note you want to use `:` not `=` in `attributes` as a object. And no strings on the left: `varName: 'value'`.

Comment: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#observerpatternjavascript

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment really.

> So i think that's okay,

No, it isn't. In the constructor the *attributes* object isn't assigned to the instance (which is assigned to the constructor's *this* when called with *new*), so you probably want (with Spencer's fixes):

```
function Movie(){
  this.attributes = {
    'title' : 'undefined',
    'duration' : '0',
    'director' : 'undefined',
    'actor' : []
  }
}
```

So now when you do:

```
var movie = new Movie();

console.log(movie.attributes.duration) // 0
```

Comment: So the correct way is to do{
this.attributes = {
  'title' : 'undefined'  // or  title : 'undefined' ?

using or not using a string as the key

Comment: @AleMoyano it doesn't matter which you choose, unless your key uses characters which are invalid variable-names `{ name : "Bob", "age+isUnemployed?" : "32:true" }`. There probably aren't a lot of times this will happen. Also, 'undefined' isn't a string in JS, unless you really want it to say 'undefined' everywhere.  Even then, the string representation of `undefined` is `"undefined"`. Also, your `Movie.prototype.method;` declarations should be `Movie.prototype.method = function () { };`

Comment: @AleMoyano—typically you wouldn't bother initialising properties to *undefined*, just leave setting them until you have a useful value.

Comment: Thanks for that, and do you know what should i do with the second excercise? I can't understand what the MovieObserver class should do.